# A method of finding the newest build of a given Windows version

Tags: java, windows, powershell

I'm looking for any kind of API or method of finding what the newest version of Windows is for a specified version. Is there any method to get this information?

Comment: What do you mean by "newest version of Windows for a specified version"?

Comment: I mean the newest build of a version e.g. find what the newest build of Windows Server 2012 is or Windows 10 Home.

Comment: How would an API know what a newer build of Windows is? (Trying to understand what's provoking the question.)

Comment: Related follow-up question: Even if you could know a future build number, what problem does this help you solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is not a dedicated API supplying latest builds per Windows versions. There are several resources on the web supplying this information, you could compile these into a data set and create an API for your own use.

For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions

Comment: This would need to constantly updated every time there's a new build (unless you have a time machine that nobody knows about <grin>).

Comment: write a web scrapper script in python (using BeautifulSoup and Selenium). Kinda your own API.

Comment: This would be rather a brittle solution because it depends on an external resource, but even if you did this, it still can't tell the future.